# Odoo: Using the same Bank Account for multiple Contacts?

Tags: odoo, payment, shared, accounting

The use case is as follows I have a payment to register and my partner contact (the business) uses a personal account under a different name.

So here's what I finally found:

It is possible to share a bank account doing the following using parent_id field of the partner (this is in 15.0 CE btw):

- in the form view of your contact:
- select the parent company in the parent_id field

That's it that should do it. Now the bank accounts should be shared. Good luck, hope it works for you.

But maybe there's a different approach to this?

I ended up doing what I mentioned previously but I worked around it for a while with manual accounting entries bridging the amount over to the other partner(s). Tedious and manual though.